# ImageResizer: Disable size limitation of resizing

Tags: c#, azure, imageresizer, azure-functions

I am using the ImageResizer (https://imageresizing.net/) library in a Azure Function which returns resized images stored in a Azure Storage Account.

Its working fine so far, but it has the limitation of resizing to maximum 3200 pixels. (https://imageresizing.net/docs/v4/plugins/sizelimiting)

Since i'm using a Azure Function I can't access a web.config to disable this limitation. Can I disable this limitation via code (maybe `ResizeSettings`)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally you'd remove the SizeLimiting plugin in `Application_Start` but we don't currently give you any hooks in Azure Functions to run startup code. We've got an issue tracking that [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/281) in our repo.

However, you can still remove the plugin in your function code before doing any image processing, e.g.:

```
using ImageResizer;
using ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic;

public static void Run(..., TraceWriter log)
{
    RemoveSizeLimiter(log);

    ...
}

private static void RemoveSizeLimiter(TraceWriter log)
{
    var config = ImageResizer.Configuration.Config.Current;
    var sizeLimiter = config.Plugins.Get<SizeLimiting>();
    log.Info("SizeLimiter installed: " + (sizeLimiter != null).ToString());

    if (sizeLimiter != null)
    {
        log.Info("Uninstalling SizeLimiter");
        sizeLimiter.Uninstall(config);
    }
}
```

If you run this function multiple times, you'll see that the plugin is removed from the static `Config.PlugIns` collection the first time, and stays removed for the lifetime of the App Domain.